# How to express relation that something belong to something, using noun phrase?

Tags: grammar, programming

I want to express the belong relation between things, but not use *of* or *'s* such as "path of file" or "file's path".

In coding, there is sometimes a need to express "belong" relation in an identifier or function name. Apostrophe (') is an invalid character for this purpose. Too many words will make the identifier ugly, such as *path_of_file*.

What good expression can I use to express it in two words?

Is there a better answer than, for example, *files_path*?

Comment: Note that naming of terms is off topic here. Though *[filepath](https://www.google.com/search?q=filepath)* itself is a known word to use. You may want to make sure it's not a reserved word for your environment.

Comment: Can you give us more examples?

Comment: @AlwaysAsking I'm Sorry for I can't find a appropriate example timely.If I find some example,I will comment here again.

Comment: @SrJoven As you say, the naming of terms is off topic here.What I want to know is whether there is another form to indicate the possessive.Do you think the meaning of *file's path* is the same as the meaning of *file path*?

Comment: @SrJoven Thank you for correcting my grammar error.

Comment: There's meaning, and there's what's understood. A file path is a path where a file is located. A file's path is a path that belongs to a file. There are valid belongs_to and other terms for relational data, but much of that question is related to the programming language or database commands being used. In programming, though, it's probably better to use a what-it-is word and explain its usage/inheritance/properties in a comment.

Comment: Just use [Tok Pisin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tok_Pisin#Grammar) and call it _path\_bilong\_file_.

Comment: And why not "chemin_appartien_fichier"? This is an English language forum not New Guinean ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use an apostrophe to indicate the possessive, then I think you have to use "of".  I can't think of any other construction that would work.  And while this may be more appropriate for StackOverflow than ELU, I wouldn't worry about usage such as `path_of_file` being "ugly". Code is one area where clarity wins over beauty every time.

Comment: thank you for your reply.I'll ask the question for StackOverflow again.

Comment: If you ask on SO, it will probably be closed as mostly opinion-based. Variable naming is based on personal style, there are no rules.